# Predict class labels with sklearn (scikit-learn) logistic regression TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, logistic-regression, predict

I am attempting to get predicted class labels using the `predict` method from `sklearn LogisticRegression`. I am able to get an accuracy score using the following code:

```
logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
logistic.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test))
```

But when I pass the test samples (`X_test`) to `predict`

```
logistic.predict(X_test))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

[Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) tells me that `predict` takes an '{array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]' as argument, and `X_test` is a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is `X_test` of the same shape/type as `X_train`?

Comment: Yes, X_test 10% of the full dataset and X_train the other 90%. They are taken from the same sparse matrix, and both seem to work with the score method.

Comment: Can you post a link to the data set?

Comment: It's not public. Original data is 2240 one line text samples. Feature were extracted with `CountVectorizer()' and `TfidfTransformer()` and a sparse matrix of shape (2240, 7342) was produced. `y_train` and `y_test` are one-dimensional arrays of the true class labels.

Comment: What I really don't get is why the error is telling me that a float is required, while the documentation says it should be an array.